# How can I modify my repository so I'm able to return child collections from a get?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have the following class:

```
public class Test
{
    public Test()
    {
        this.TestQuestions = new List<TestQuestion>();
    }
    public int TestId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TestQuestion> TestQuestions { get; set; }
}
```

In my repository:

```
public virtual T GetById(int id)
{
    return DbSet.Find(id);
}
```

I want to get an entity by giving it the id so I am doing this in my service:

```
public Test GetTest(int testId)
{
    var test = _testsRepository
            .GetById(testId);
   return test;
}
```

However the Test entity has a collection and it's not including the collection.

Can someone tell me how I can make it so the call to the repository allows me to also  as for the collection? What I am hoping for is to make it so in the service I have a .Include and a LINQ query.

Comment: So you have a repository that wraps a DbSet, a service that wraps a repository and then a method in a class that wraps a service... Are you willing to reconsider this and to flatten the architecture so you can access DbSet (more) directly in `GetTest`?

Comment: I'd like to be able to issue a LINQ type query in my service if possible that has a .Include

Comment: DbSet is an implementation of the repository pattern. What are you trying to achieve by wrapping this in your own repository? Why not use the DbSet directly from the service?

Comment: @MartinBooth - Can you give me an example of how I could do this?

Comment: Instead of calling the _testsRespository.GetById method in the service, put the code you wrote in the _testsRespository.GetById (i.e. DbSet.Find(id);) into the service. That way you can use features of entity framework (such as the include method) without having to find away to map them through a repository

Comment: @MartinBooth - Hi Martin, I appreciate your suggestions but I think this is getting away from the original question.

Comment: The point is, of course you can parametrize includes, but you have to dig through a few layers to get the parameters where they they finally have effect. Same discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19393748/entity-framework-5-is-it-possible-to-load-relationships-associations-without#comment29110680_19393748